# preload all content

Tags: jquery, html, video, load

I have a page that I display a number of images and video in a type of slideshow, however I want to determine if all content on the page has currently loaded before I start. Does

$(window).load()

Check to see if all content, including video has been loaded?

cheers
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load()` checks to see if a page is fully loaded including all images.  As per the [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

> Example: Run a function when the page is fully loaded including
>   graphics. `$(window).load(function () {   // run code });`

Basically `$(document).ready()` checks to see if the HTML document is fully loaded and parsed, `$(window).load()` will wait until all resources have been requested and (if found) loaded into the webpage, this includes all images.

If you're looking to do something after a video has loaded, you may use `$(window).load()`, but I'd suggest using a callback function.  If you're using an API like YouTube, Vimeo, or Brightcove then I'd suggest using a callback of their library rather than using `$(window).load()`, this is because if you're getting video data from a remote server, there's no way for jQuery (client-side) to inherently know if the video has finished streaming.  jQuery would however know if the script it took to connect to the remote source has loaded.